# Laravel request being routed through wrong middleware

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2

I want to add a http response header to all my responses on my app. I've just created a new middleware in order to do this as follows:

```
namespace Ibbr\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class XFrameOptionsHeader
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'deny');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then, added it to my `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\XFrameOptionsHeader::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],



protected $routeMiddleware = [

    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verificaCookieArquivo' => \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\VerificaCookieArquivo::class,
    'xFrameOptionsHeader' => \Ibbr\Http\Middleware\XFrameOptionsHeader::class,
]
```

and in the routes definition I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['verificaCookieArquivo']], function(){
    Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'PagesController@getArquivo');
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>['web','xFrameOptionsHeader']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
    // more routes...
});
```

Whenever I call any route in the second group `['web','xFrameOptionsHeader']` **it works normally and return the new http header**. But, when I call the route `/storage/{filename}` it fails with the error

> Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()

So first of all before considering if the header function exists or not in this context, I find it more strange that this middleware is even being called in this situation where I thought that it would call only the `verificaCookieArquivo` mid. Why does this happen and how to solve? Btw, I'm using laravel-5.7 but thre's not tag for it.

Comment: may I see the whole `middlewareGroups`?

Comment: In many cases with add `web` middleware problem solved.`'middleware'=>['web','verificaCookieArquivo']`

Comment: @Wreigh I've added it to the OP.

Comment: @Saman I've tried this but didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `\Ibbr\Http\Middleware\XFrameOptionsHeader::class,` from your `web` middleware groups.

`web` middleware group is automatically applied to `routes/web.php`. Thus that's why the middleware is ran on:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['verificaCookieArquivo']], function(){
    Route::get('/storage/{filename}', 'PagesController@getArquivo');
});
```

Moreover, you do not need to specify `web` in your next route group as well:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web','xFrameOptionsHeader']], function(){
                            // ^-- Remove this
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
    // more routes...
});
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-groups